# duplicated column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

users
tickets
Activity

with relationship 1:n ---<-

users 1:n ticket (users can create many tickets)

ticket 1:n Activity (A tickets could have many activities)

Users 1:n Activity (A user can create many Activities that belong to a ticket)

I want to write a query that gives me

username ! ticket ! username ! activities

I try using Inner join but I only have the iduser (PK), and I need the column names.

I don't know how can I difference both names from users table. the first name was the user who create the ticket and the other the user who create the activity and both could be different.

Answer (score 0):

try using alias.

```
select user.username as user_username, activities.username as act_username from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

join on the users table twice, once with tickets, once with activities

```
select u1.username, a.ticket, u2.username, b.activity 
from tickets a
join activities b on a.ticketid = b.ticketid
join users u1 on a.userid = u1.userid
join users u2 on b.userid = u2.userid
```

Comment: man! I really thanks you!!!! It take me a few minutes adapt your example to my enviroment but I works!!!

I started studing mysql a few days ago and you really helped me on what I want to do... thanks man!